# Что значит тип первого параметра должен быть "code"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть код:

```
def f():
    pass

function = type(f)
```

теперь в `function` лежит класс `function`. Класс `function` принимает два аргумента, тип первого параметра должен быть `code`, если передать объект другого типа то выходит ошибка. нигде не нашёл информации про `code`.

Comment: `help(f.__code__)`

Comment: и еще https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#code-objects

Answer (score 1):

Это объект кода. Плюс-минус такой-же как скомпилированный в `compile(code)`.

Его наверно просто функция исполняет.

А объект code - это `f.__code__`

Comment: И вообще я не согласен с ответом. Во первых есть прекрасная документация — так что исходный код смореть последнее дело. Во-вторых смысл туда "лазать" есть.